# Strange apply() behavior in R returning different values with different value ranges and even when function entered alone?

Tags: r, function, boolean, apply

Ever seen this behavior and why?

I'll summarize my problem then clarify more:
I have a function "my_function()", which works. It *always* worked when I use it individually.
When I use apply() on it, I get wrong outputs sometimes. Example:

`apply(working_data[933266:933267,], 1, my_function)` gets me unwanted NAs.
`apply(working_data[933265:933266,], 1, my_function)` works fine.
`apply(working_data[933267:933268,], 1, my_function)` works fine.

Why is apply() behaving like this?

### I'll clarify more:

I have a function that works fine, it returns for me a named  vector of logicals.

I'll give an example of its output:

`my_function(working_data[933267,])`

> ```
>  320170356871 174173601732 172156573581 320004381381 320210363581 ...
>      FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE    ...
> ```

`my_function(working_data[933266,])`

> ```
>  320170356871 174173601732 172156573581 320004381381 320210363581 ...
>      FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE    ...
> ```

Ok, this is correct and fine (no NAs, and the output is different between the two examples, don't let those repetitive FALSEs fool you, I checked).

Now I want to apply it to rows of a dataframe. Whenever I do, it works for a while, and then suddenly starts returning NAs everywhere and forever after! (note that I'm going to use the same indices as above):

`apply(working_data[933266:933267,], 1, my_function)`

```
 |     |933266 |  933267|
 |-----|-------|--------|
 |[1,] |FALSE  |  NA    |
 |[2,] |FALSE  |  NA    |
 |[3,] |FALSE  |  NA    |
 |[4,] |FALSE  |  NA    |
 |[5,] |FALSE  |  NA    |
 |...  |  ...  |   ...  |
```

This is what I see. In fact what I get is everything to the left of 933266 (i.e. from 1 to 933266) is correct, and everything to the right of 933267 is NAs.

The expected output is this:

```
 |     |933266 |  933267|
 |-----|-------|--------|
 |[1,] |FALSE  |  FALSE |
 |[2,] |FALSE  |  FALSE |
 |[3,] |FALSE  |  FALSE |
 |[4,] |FALSE  |  FALSE |
 |[5,] |FALSE  |  FALSE |
 |...  |  ...  |   ...  |
```

And note that, when I try `apply(working_data[933265:933266,], 1, my_function)` and `apply(working_data[933267:933268,], 1, my_function)` I get correct results!

So it is returning NAs only for that interval: `apply(working_data[933266:933267,], 1, my_function)`

And I can't seem to understand why!

Also note that I *always* get correct results when running a for-loop.

Are there any theoretical explanations for this (hopefully without the need of providing a reproducible example.. I'm too deep in my code)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think we can help without at least seeing the function's code.

Comment: Thanks for the interest @Roland. I solved it. If you are still curious, check the answer below.

Comment: Impossible to find without a reproducible example. See why you are supposed to provide one? You would have found the error and never posted this question if you had created a MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it. The problem is that a value from the dataset has a trailing whitespace and was passed to one of the arguments of the function.

When I was applying the function individually (or via a for-loop), it seemed that R  automatically dealt with the trailing whitespace and just ignored it.

Also, when starting the apply() function from a value that includes trailing whitespace (row # 933267 in my case), apply() won't detect it nor throw an NA nor an error, and will just continue normally.. this explains why I was having clean results with `apply(working_data[933267:933268,], 1, my_function)`

But, when the value having a trailing whitespace is in the middle of the value range (i.e. not the first value), the function will show the above mentioned behavior, and will return those confusing NAs. This explains the bad results in `apply(working_data[933266:933267,], 1, my_function)`

I wish though it had been more consistent; apply() should have throwed NAs even when the first value has a trailing whitespace in it (i.e. when I called  `apply(working_data[933267:933268,], 1, my_function)`). Had this been done, I would have detected this much earlier.

Comment: My guess is that it is your function that is inconsistent, not `apply`, but that's just a guess, since we don't have your data or your function.